# No route matches error in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

my

```
describe PaymentController do

 it 'should assign amount_to_pay' do

  get bank_payment_path, {id: "1"}

  expect(assigns[:amount_to_pay]).to eq "123"
 end
end
```

my error:

```
Error: ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:action=>"bank", :controller=>"payment"}
```

and rake routes:

```
  bank_payment GET    /payment/:id/bank(.:format)             payment#bank
```

What is wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request should be:

```
get :bank, id: "1"
```